# How to render tuples in bottlepy

Tags: python, templates, bottle

I have been using bottlepy and i have a thing like this:

```
..code..
comments = [(u'34782439', 78438845, 6, u'hello im nick'), 
(u'34754554', 7843545, 5, u'hello im john'), 
(u'332432434', 785345545, 3, u'hello im phil')] 

return comments
```

In the view i have done this:

```
%for address date user text in comments:
      <h3>{{address}}</h3>
      <h3>{{date}}</h3>
      <h3>{{user}}</h3>
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>
%end
```

When i start the server, the error is:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

Sorry, the requested URL http://localhost:8080/hello caused an error:

Unsupported response type: <type 'tuple'>
```

How could i render it into the view?

(im sorry for my english)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has two problems. First, response cannot be a list of tuples. It can be a string or a list of strings, as Peter suggests, or, in case you want to use the view, it can (and should) be a dictionary of view variables. Keys are variable names (these names, such as `comments`, will be available in the view), values are arbitrary objects.

So, your handler function can be rewritten as:

```
@route('/')
@view('index')
def index():
    # code
    comments = [
        (u'34782439', 78438845, 6, u'hello im nick'), 
        (u'34754554', 7843545, 5, u'hello im john'), 
        (u'332432434', 785345545, 3, u'hello im phil')]
    return { "comments": comments }
```

Notice the `@view` and `@route` decorators.

Now, you have a problem in your view code: the commas in tuple unpacking are missing. Therefore, your view (named `index.html` in my case) should look like:

```
%for address, date, user, text in comments:
    <h3>{{address}}</h3>
    <h3>{{date}}</h3>
    <h3>{{user}}</h3>
    <h3>{{text}}</h3>
%end
```

Comment: I had view and route decorators, "..code.." was an abbreviation for them.. My error was "return comments" and the commas. Thankyou very much for your helps! I'm new in python and something isn't clear still..

Answer (score 4):

I believe bottle expects either a string or a list of strings, so you may need to convert it and parse.

```
 return str(result)
```

For ways of formatting results, have a look at the section "**Bottle Template To Format The Output**" at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html